# How can I configure Codeigniter in NGINX server? .htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, nginx

How can I configure Codeigniter in NGINX server? .htaccess is not working here and i have **no root permission**. Only I can upload files using FTP and can access database.

where can I use this config...?

```
    server {
        server_name domain.tld;

        root /var/www/codeignitor;
        index index.html index.php;

        # set expiration of assets to MAX for caching
        location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location / {
                # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~* \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                include fastcgi.conf;
        }
}
```

Ref: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/

Comment: Ask your cloud provider and they will tell you

Comment: .htaccess is not supported in nginx.

Answer (score 0):

You should talk to your network admin for access of configuration files /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf. which needs to be configured correctly to make your routing work.you can configure your nginx server file like this code to make your routing work.

```
server{ listen 80; listen [::]:80; server_name 192.168.56.101 192.168.101.100 localhost; root /var/www/html; index index.php index.html index.htm; location / { try_files $uri $uri/ =404; } error_page 404 /404.html; error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html; location = /50x.html { root /var/www/html; } location /ci { try_files $uri $uri/ /ci/index.php?/$request_uri; }location ~ \.php$ { try_files $uri $uri/ /ci/index.php?/$request_uri; fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock; fastcgi_index index.php; fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; include fastcgi_params; } location ~ /\.ht { deny all; } }
```